# How to use use a custom model?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, model-view-controller, model

I trying to use a custom model to populate a tableView it is not working.

In cellAtRow method my instance of the custom object is null.

**SmsModel.h**

```
@interface SmsModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *carrierId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *carrierName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *phoneNumber;
- (id)initWithData :(NSString *)phoneNumber : (NSString *)carrierId;
@end
```

**SmsModel.m**

```
#import "SmsModel.h"

@implementation SmsModel
- (id)initWithData :(NSString *)phoneNumber : (NSString *)carrierId
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        self.carrierId = carrierId;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Now here is how I set the values

```
NSArray *data = result[@"data"];
for (NSDictionary *smsData in data) {
    SmsModel * smsObj = [[SmsModel alloc]initWithData:smsData[@"input"]: smsData[@"crr_id"]];
    NSLog(@"smsObjphoneNumber=%@", smsObj.phoneNumber);//works
    [self.SmsDataArray addObject:smsObj];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Now it fails when I want to get the value

```
SmsModel * smsObj = self.SmsDataArray[indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"smsObj.phoneNumber %@",smsObj.phoneNumber);
```

When I log anything it's null.

I even tried casting

```
SmsModel * smsObj =  (SmsModel *)self.SmsDataArray[indexPath.row];
```

still null.

**EDIT**

I initialized the array:

```
self.SmsDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

but now i get an error:

> ```
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 ..
> ```
>
> 0]'
>       *** First throw call stack:
>       (0x2e73ae83 0x38a976c7 0x2e670d95 0xb4a35 0x30ff1315 0x30f996cd 0x30f98ef1 0x30ebf353 0x30b45943 0x30b41167 0x30b40ff9 0x30b40a0d
>   0x30b4081f 0x30b3a54d 0x2e705f69 0x2e7038f7 0x2e703c43 0x2e66e471
>   0x2e66e253 0x333a82eb 0x30f23845 0xa4705 0x38f90ab7)
>       libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Did you instantiate your SmsDataArray?

Comment: no I did not , do I have to ? @rdelmar

Comment: Of course you do. You can't add objects to a nonexistent array.

Comment: @rdelmar I Initiliazed it now I get an error, please check my edit

Comment: What are you returning in numberOfRowsInSection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now it fails when I want to get the value

That's probably because you haven't created the array `self.SmsDataArray`. If that property is `nil`, any method you call on it (including `objectAtIndex:` or the shorthand equivalent) will return nil.

> `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 ..`

Here the message pretty much tells you what the problem is. You're trying to access a non-existent item in the array. Try surrounding your array access with a conditional, like this:

```
if (indexPath.row < [self.SmsDataArray count]) {
    return self.SmsDataArray[indexPath.row];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Oops, I just tried to access a non-existent element from the array!");
}
```

Chances are that this is happening because you somehow have more rows in your table than items in your array.

Comment: I get it now, but I have an error can you see my edit?

Comment: thanks bro, I can't vote u up yet  but i really appreciate it